# LWC navigation error: "this[f.NavigationMixin.Navigate] is not a function"

Tags: lightning-web-components, error-messages, navigation, navigationmixin.navigate

When attempting to use the Lightning navigation service in my component's base class (.js), I get the following error when functionally testing in the UI:

> this[f.NavigationMixin.Navigate] is not a function

I am calling the **NavigationMixin** function provided by the **lightning/navigation** module.

I have imported the module:

```js
    import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
```

And am calling the function as below:

```js
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.org.Id,
            objectApiName: 'Account',
            actionName: 'view'
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is embarrassing, but I'm going to tell you what I did. I did not capitalize the N in **N**avigation**M**ixin on the import. Hopefully this saves 5 more minutes of searching you still have issues after getting your default class export right.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Apply the `NavigationMixin` function to your component’s base class:

```
export default class MyLwcComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
```

Hopefully this saves 3 mins of searching for those who (like me) only skimmed the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) before diving in :)

Comment: thanks I had forgotten this part, luckily I put the error in and got your answer!!!!