# LWC: lightning-navigation is not a function

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation

I am trying to use the navigation to custom sObject record edit page by passing recordid as mentioned in the document. However, it says "it is not a function".

Any thoughts?

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

navigateToCorpconEdit(row) {
        let { linkName } = row;            
        let recordid = linkName.substr(1);

        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: recordid,
                objectApiName: 'npe5__Affiliation__c',
                actionName: 'edit'
            },
        });
    }
```

**Error**:

> [this[h.NavigationMixin.Navigate] is not a function]

Comment: It looks like you have not put your method in a class, I don't know if you are abbreviating your code, but you need to have an **export default class NavigateToSomething extends NavigatoinMixin(LightningElement){ ... }** . You will also need to include **import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LWC Navigation: "this\[f.NavigationMixin.Navigate\] is not a function"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254496/lwc-navigation-thisf-navigationmixin-navigate-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a comment but it looks like you are missing the export, and extending the MixIn.  So your code needs to look more like this:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class NavToSomething extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    navigateToCorpconEdit(row) {
        let { linkName } = row;            
        let recordid = linkName.substr(1);

        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: recordid,
                objectApiName: 'npe5__Affiliation__c',
               actionName: 'edit'
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I missed extends the NavigationMixin, good learning..:)